# How to add string object in nsmutable array if some string is empty

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, nsmutablearray

```
arrdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:strname,strWeb,strAdd,strPhone,strrate, nil];  
[arrAllData addObject:arrdata];
```

I fetched data from a webservice. in my condition if `strweb` has no value then it simply ignores other values like `stradd`,`sphone` and `strrate`. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can do like this in a simplest way.

```
if(strweb==nil)  
{  
  strweb=@"null";   
}
```

**Note:** pass null in <> bracket;

Answer (score 1):

Try this code,

```
if(strWeb == nil){
        strWeb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [NSNull null]];
    }
    arrdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:strname,strWeb,strAdd,strPhone,strrate, nil];  
                [arrAllData addObject:arrdata];
```

When your any object nil while creation time of array then your array will be end with than object and remaining objects will discards. That why you need to check every object should not be nil according above code stuff then add it into array.

If strWeb is nil then your array structure will be

```
arrdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:strname,nil]; future object will discard.,strAdd,strPhone,strrate,
```

output of arrdata containg only one object strname

**Other way,**

Set any default value if your string is nil. for example,

```
if(strWeb == nil){
            strWeb = @"This Value is discarded"; // It could be anything identifier for your purpose.
        }
        arrdata=[[NSMutableArray alloc]initWithObjects:strname,strWeb,strAdd,strPhone,strrate, nil];  
                    [arrAllData addObject:arrdata];
```

While retrieving time you can match above string with value inside the object.

Comment: @sanjeet see now output you got properly or not.

Answer (score 0):

You use the initializer `-initWithObjects:`. As you know the object list is terminated with `nil`. If one of the references has the value `nil`, `-initWithObjects:` thinks that this is the terminator.

Check the references (i. e. strweb). If it is `nil`, assign a default value to it or do not encounter the variable in the list.